# Is 靠 structure "A 靠 B do something"?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

```
他们全家靠父亲一个人工作生活。Their family get by on their dad's salary.
他们靠经营宾馆发了财。They make fortune by hotel business.
```

There are my questions

(1) Is 靠 structure "A (pronoun/noun) 靠 B (pronoun/noun) do something"?

(2) Can I say：

他们全家的生活靠父亲一个人工作。

他们收入靠经营宾馆。

(3) Are there any special notices involving 靠 structure?

Comment: It seems that you got it right. All your sentences are correct.

Comment: so are there any special notices?

Comment: 他们全家靠父亲一个人工作生活。 is wrong.  I missed it.

Comment: Can you explain why it is wrong?

Comment: 他们全家靠父亲一个人工作生活 should be 他们全家靠父亲一个人工作(來維持)生活

Comment: 工作生活 = work live; 工作(來維持)生活 = work to maintain live

Comment: 他们全家靠父亲一个人工作生活 implies that "Their family depend on their dad working to survive/to get by", but it should be made more completed by adding 來維持, right?

Comment: @Jenny 他们全家靠父亲一个人工作来生活 is a complete version. 他们全家靠父亲一个人工作生活 might be ok colloquially, especially when we take it as a shorthand of 他们全家靠父亲一个人工作来生活.  But grammatically I suggest the version with 来.

Comment: Thanks Dan and Tang Ho!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is 靠 structure "A (pronoun/noun) 靠 B (pronoun/noun) do something"?

The thing  missing is 'to achieve something'

> "A (pronoun/noun) 靠 B (pronoun/noun) to do something to achieve something"

- 他们全家的生活靠父亲一个人工作 = the whole family's living depend on the father working alone
- 他们全家的生活靠父亲一个人工作(來維持) = the whole family's living depend on the father working alone (to maintain)

(*"to maintain living, the whole family depend on the father to work alone*".  Not "生活(subject) 靠 父亲一个人工")

- 他们的收入靠经营宾馆 = their income depend on running an inn
- 他们的收入靠经营宾馆(而來) = their income depend on running an inn (to obtain)

(*to obtain income, they depend on running an inn* . Not 收入(subject) 靠 经营宾馆)

Note:

If 靠 means 'solely depend on' you should use the full term 全靠 instead of just 靠

- 他们全家的生活全靠父亲一个人工作來維持 = the whole family's living solely depend on the father working alone to maintain
- 他们的收入全靠经营宾馆而來 = their income sole depend on running an inn to obtain

A simpler example

汽車依靠汽油 (car depend on gas)

汽車依靠汽油來運行 (car depend on gas to run)

Comment: So, the listener still understands what I mean but my sentences are not completed because they lack of "purpose", right?

Comment: purpose is implied, see my edition at the bottom. 汽車依靠汽油 imply 汽車依靠汽油來運行

Comment: @Jenny I think the idea is that in speech, it's often ok to leave out the last part of the sentence because the listener can easily fill in the missing part; but in writing, it's best to flesh out the idea fully to maintain the grammatical integrity of the sentence (unless  you are quoting the speech of a character in your writing of course)

Comment: You're right! Many Chinese people tell me that.